# What attacks can you do on HMAC to get the key?

Tags: hash, cryptography, hmac

I'm doing a CTF challenge where you have to try and figure out the key used for a HMAC, you get given two example strings and their hashes (which are 512 bit) and also a hint to use a number between 40 and 50. What sort of attacks can you do on HMAC, and is it possible to recover the key?

Comment: Is this HMAC-SHA512? HMACs parameters are bytes, so you will have to find the correct way to encode these small integers as bytes. I would start simple and just encode the integers as single bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If the hash function that is being used by HMAC is cryptographically secure then the only way to solve this is to brute force the key. Hashes are one-way function where it is easy to apply the hash but very hard to do the opposite. Since the search space is indefinite, this is infeasible in the general case but you seem to have a hint about the key.

Perhaps this should be seen as a literal hint and you write a loop that starts with a key of `"40"` and iterate up to `"50"` and check if any of the the example strings match with any of the hashes. If you found a match then you check if the other pairing also leads to a match with the same key.

Comment: I've tried using the numbers as keys but I don't think it's that simple. Do you think its possible that the numbers could be used for something else, like padding for the keys?

Comment: I don't think so. More hints might be there in a way that the task is presented.

Comment: There were some hints about XOR, maybe the hash function could be to do with that and not SHA-512.

Comment: Oh, so you don't even know the hash function. In that case, no idea. As James mentioned, you might need to get creative with the encoding like doing hex or octal in two ways: 1. assuming 40 is already hex/octal and transforming it into either bytes or decimal or 2. assuming 40 is decimal and transforming it into hex or octal. Those are 6 additional ways to read that. XOR is not a hash function, so no idea how that fits into the challenge.

Comment: I've figured out that the hash function is indeed SHA-512, is there no way to find the key without bruteforce as the hash function is secure?

Comment: Exactly, but since this is a CTF the hint reduces the search space considerably.